# Why does my Arduino serial port gives me semi-random numbers?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

I have a basic problem with my Arduino Uno.
My example code gets a number over Serial port and should print it back.

```cpp
int incomingByte = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello World");  
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    // read the incoming byte:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();

    // say what you got:
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
  }
}
```

When I send 0, I receive 48.

```
0->48
1->49
2->50
3->51

a->97
b->98
A->65
```

So why doesn't it send the same numbers back to me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your program the output is [ASCII equivalent](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html) of the input that the Arduino receives. ASCII equivalent of 0 is 48, 1 is 49, a is 97, A is 65 and so on.

The reason is you are storing your input to `incomingByte` variable (`incomingByte = Serial.read();`) but you declare `incomingByte` variable as `int`. When a character is assigned to integer variable, its corresponding ASCII value will be stored to the [integer variable](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/ASCII-value-character).

So if you want to print a character that you send to the Arduino, you want to change `int incomingByte = 0;` to `char incomingByte;`.